# How to deploy a war file to Jetty?

Tags: jetty, sbt, war

I'm using an open source project that produces a war. I want to deploy this to a Jetty server. I want to create an sbt project with a Main class where it fires up a jetty server, and then deploy above war to it.

The problem I'm facing is how to tell jetty to deploy the war. Even if I made the war as a dependency, still I would not have the war physically in my project.

One thing I tried was add

```
retrieveManaged := true
```

in `build.sbt`, where it copied all the dependencies to the `managed_lib` folder, but that looks ugly.

I cannot move the war project in to SBT

Any good ways to do this?

Comment: Before you automate it with sbt, do you know how to do it with Jetty and war themselves (without sbt)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps you need to take are basically the following:

1. Create an sbt task that gives you access to the war file
2. Communicate the location of the war file to your code
3. Tell Jetty the location of the file

---

Note that the code is untested, but it should give you something to go on

1.

```
val warFile = taskKey[File]("A reference to the war file")

warFile := {
  val filter = artifactFilter(name = "name of warfile")
  val updateReport = update.value
  updateReport.filter(filter).toSeq.headOption.map {
    case (config, module, artifact, file) => file
  }.getOrElse(sys.error("Could not find a warfile"))
}
```

2.

In `project/buildinfo.sbt` add `addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-buildinfo" % "0.3.2")`

```
buildInfoPackage := "your.package",
buildInfoObject := "BuildInfo",
buildInfoKeys := Seq[BuildInfoKey](
  warFile
),
sourceGenerators in Compile <+= buildInfo
```

3.

```
val warFile = new File(BuildInfo.warFile)
// pass to Jetty
```